# django findstatic not looking in every directory

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

`findstatic` has a strange behaviour :

1. On localhost

`python manage.py findstatic pic/xxx.jpg -v 3` gives me :

```
Found 'pic/xxx.jpg' here:
  /[...]/myapp/app1/static/pix/xxx.jpg
Looking in the following locations:
  /[...]/myapp/app1/static
  /[...]/myapp/app2/static
  /[...]/myapp/app3/static
  /[...]/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
```

2. whereas on production

it gives me

```
Found 'pic/xxx.jpg' here:
  /[...]/myapp/app1/static/pic/xxx.jpg
Looking in the following locations:
  /[...]/myapp/app1/static
  /[...]/myapp/app2/static
  /[...]/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
```

(note that the 'app3' directory isn't looked into, despite it exists)

Of course, the files located in the 'app3' directory are not found by findstatic, although they exist.

Does someone have any idea where the problem could come from ? (I don't have any special parameter for staticfiles).

Comment: Do you have different settings for develop and production

Comment: What are your INSTALLED_APPS in production?

Comment: 'app1.apps.App1Config',
'app2.apps.App2Config',
'app3.apps.App3Config',
that's why I don't understand why the two first apps work but not the third one