# Django findstatic: "No matching file found" but the file is there

Tags: django, heroku, django-staticfiles, whitenoise

On a Django 1.11 app deployed to Heroku. The Django management command `findstatic` is saying that it cannot find a file `angular.min.js` even though the file appears to be in a folder findstatic is checking.

```
$ heroku run python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 angular.min.js
Running python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 angular.min.js
No matching file found for 'angular.min.js'.

Looking in the following locations:
  /app/static
  /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static
  /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_extensions/static
  /app/.heroku/src/django-floppyforms/floppyforms/static
  /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/static
$ heroku run ls /app/static/angular/
Running ls /app/static/angular/
angular.min.js  controllers.js
```

So it appears that `angular.min.js` is at /app/static/angular/. Why does `findstatic` not find it?

### Relevant part of settings.py:

I followed [Heroku's instructions for service Static Files with Django](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets):

```py
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    # ...others here too
]
```

Also, `whitenoise` in requirements.txt

### Related questions that did not solve my problem:

[Django findstatic : No matching file found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32415312/django-findstatic-no-matching-file-found) (STATICFILES_DIRS appears to me to be correctly set up)
[django findstatic not looking in every directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41969323/django-findstatic-not-looking-in-every-directory) (In my situation, findstatic appears to be looking in the correct parent directory)

Comment: It must look under /app/static/angular but it is looking in /app/static

Comment: try to place your  angular.min.js in app/static/

Comment: what is the path of angular.min.js  you are using in html file? it should be /angular/angular.min.js if you want to access from angular file

Comment: Or leave it there and try `heroku run python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 angular/angular.min.js`.

Comment: `$ heroku run python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 angular/angular.min.js` This does find the file. I assumed findstatic would look into sub-folders. Guess not.

Comment: The HTML template is loading the file with `{% static 'angular/angular.min.js' %}` so that appears to be fine. However (as you probably guessed) there's an error for that. I'll post a different SO question for that error, because it's not a `findstatic` error. Thanks.

Comment: Update: the other question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57928946/django-valueerror-missing-staticfiles-manifest-entry-but-the-manifest-appears